# The density of Z|X, Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, density-function

If we have given that $\bf{Y} | \bf{X} \sim N(\bf{\mu}, \bf{\Sigma})$ and

$$\bf{Z} = A\bf{Y} + \bf{\varepsilon}$$

where $\bf{\varepsilon} \sim N(\bf{0}, \bf{\Omega})$, how can we show that

$$Z|X, Y \sim N(\bf{AY}, \bf{\Omega})$$.

I tried with Bayes rule but was not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the distribution $Z|X, Y$ depends on some fixed $Y$ (some fixed outcome of the probabilistic distribution of $Y$). It means that the randomness of $Z$ is fully determined by $\varepsilon$, and $Z$ has a normal distribution with a shifted mean $AY$ and the same deviation (correlation matrix) as $\varepsilon$.

We denote by $f$ the density function.

$$f_{\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{X,Y}}(z) = f(\mathbf{Z} = z~| \mathbf{X}=x, \mathbf{Y}=y) = f(\mathbf{AY} + \varepsilon = z~| \mathbf{X}=x, \mathbf{Y}=y) = f(\varepsilon = z - \mathbf{AY}~| \mathbf{X}=x, \mathbf{Y}=y) = f_{\varepsilon}(z-\mathbf{AY}|\mathbf{X}=x, \mathbf{Y} = y) = f_{\varepsilon}(z-\mathbf{A}y)$$
which means that $Z|X,Y$ is just shifted $\varepsilon$

Comment: Yes, I can see that. How do we write it mathematically?

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thanks :). Isn't it actually the conditional density of $\varepsilon$ given X?

Comment: There's probably abuse notation along the lines, but the transitions are correct. In the expression $f(\mathbf{AY} + \varepsilon = z | \mathbf{X}=x, \mathbf{Y}=y)$ we already have the randomness concentrated only in $\varepsilon$. It may be easier to reason if you replace the density functions with probabilities: $\Pr[\mathbf{Z} = z | \ldots] = \Pr[\mathbf{AY} + \varepsilon | \ldots] = \Pr[\varepsilon = z-Ay]$.